# Language i18n setlang not working django 1.7.9

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have recently tried to implement internationalizion in my django app.

My `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates",     "locale"),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
)
```

I have also included `url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),` To my `urls.py`.

And my language changing form looks like the following:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Go" %}" />
</form>
```

I ran the commands `makemessages -l hu` and filled in the .po files, and later ran the command `compilemessages`.

The problem is that when I try to change the language using the above form, I get a 302 http response, and django simply returns to the same message it was before, and the language doesn't change, it stays english (en). Any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server manually?

Comment: Currently its only running locally, so all I did is restarted it locally (with ctrl+c + manage.py runserver)

Comment: Oddly, when I change LANGUAGE_CODE in settings to 'hu', the page will load with translations. The view is not working for some reason...